Movie where a man teaches adult English classes and is fired for correcting vandalism in the school bathroom
There's this guy who teaches English to adult learners at night school and the students want to learn how to swear.
Later on in the movie, the teacher is in the bathroom and there is vandalism on the wall with his name. He gets upset that the student didn't spell something so he takes out a marker and corrects the grammar of the vandalism on the wall. His boss comes in and sees this then fires him for doing so.

Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIAdHEwiAy8 :)

I'm certain this is from the original UK Being Human episode "Educating Creature". George the reluctant werewolf picks up a job as a ESL teacher. The bathroom scene:

George: "Mr. Sands Suck Cocks"? For God's sake! It's "Mr. Sands Sucks Cocks" - singular, not plural. Have I taught you nothing?

He fixes it with a marker.
The Headmaster catches him, and fires him for it. And gets beaten for doing so.
